# How to clean and refurbish a Victorinox Swiss Army Knife?

Tags: gear-care, repairs, knives, swiss-army-knife

I have an old Swiss Army Knife on which I can only open one blade; the rest are locked in place.  How should I clean this, and is there anything else I should do to refurbish it, like oiling, after I clean it?

This knife has been part of my daily carry for over a decade, and I carry it when I exercise, so I'm sure the innards are packed with some combination of pocket grunge, old candy and sweat.

The one blade I can still pull out works great, but the other blades are nice too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When mine gets too bad I use WD40 to free it up, then clean with soapy water and a brush. Mine also goes through the dishwasher sometimes, with the blades partially open. If it gets gummed up with sugary stuff (your candy, or cutting up fruit) a good soak in hot water will free up the blades.

After cleaning it is a good time to sharpen it. If the hinges are still stiff, a drop of light oil (3 in 1 or bike chain oil) at each hinge should do the trick. Work the oil in by opening and closing all the blades a couple of times before assuming you didn't use enough, then wipe any excess off before putting it in your pocket. You  could wrap it in a tissue the first day you carry it in your pocket, in case oil escapes when warmed by body heat - I used to carry one when I wore a suit.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I soaked it overnight in hot soapy water, brushed it out this morning while working the blades, rinsed liberally, then blew it dry with compressed air.  I finished with a touch of bike chain oil (which you probably knew I'd have around here) at each pivot.  Much better now. :)

Answer (score 16):

The producer offers a page of care instructions on their website ([here](https://www.victorinox.com/de/en/Service/Swiss-Army-Knives/Swiss-Army-Knives-Care-Tips/cms/service-swiss-army-knife-care-tips)) (PDF). The gist is:

- don't use a dishwasher, that might be too aggressive
- open and close the blade multiple times in warm water
- dry thoroughly
- put some oil on the friction points (where the blades rotate), open and close multiple times

@chris-h's answer is also spot on. I, too, use a dishwasher (the producer discourages it). I saw some oxidation of the aluminium parts between the blades after that.

Comment: Mine is ancient, I not sure if it's got any aluminium parts.

Comment: Don't know. Mine's not ancient, but 25 years old :-)

Comment: Comparable to mine then.

Comment: Mine's vintage 1985.  The blades could use sharpening but aren't too bad.  There's some small-scale corrosion on the broad plates in the body of the knife, but overall still very usable (now that I can open it again).

Comment: Gosh!  I wish I could keep my pocketknives for more than a few years.  They seem to wander away, or drop into deep crevices after a year or two.  Alas, when someone borrows my knife, I have a compulsion to *bird dog* them until they return it.

Comment: _bird dog_.. had to look that up; `bird dog` (North American) verb 1. `search out or pursue with dogged determination`

Comment: @wallyk That's me for the keyring types (which are all I carry on my person these days).  The full-size knives never seemed too easy to lose.

Comment: I keep my (small) knife on a lanyard since I dropped one on side of a train seat. I could touch it but I could not get it out before my stop.